# angular js - data not binding from controller to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm learning to make my first angularJS app, and am having trouble getting the data to bind. The code is at https://github.com/findjashua/angular

In views/index.jade, `{{understand}}` is not getting the value of `$scope.understand` from public/javascripts/maincontroller.js

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with AngularJS: when specifying the static folder on Express, you don't need to put "public" in your assets URL. Your javascript files would look like this:

```
script(src='/javascripts/app.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='/javascripts/maincontroller.js', type='text/javascript')
```

You could had figured it using [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: Also, as an extra tip, most of the cases you don't need to register your `node_modules` folder into Github. Add them to a `.gitignore` file and use `npm install` to manage your dependencies.

Comment: That worked, thanks! This is my first time doing client side development, so I'd appreciate any pointers to other tools I should be using.